# How to use having on un-aggregate field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, having-clause

```
select xx as fieldA from ... group by xxx having fieldA is not null
```

I found that `having` has no effect

Comment: Please close it,it's a bug of 5.0

Answer (score 0):

May be :

```
 select xx as fieldA from ... where fieldA is not null group by xxx having
```

help you

Comment: This won't work because aliases are not available in `GROUP BY`.  (They are in `ORDER BY` and `HAVING`).  Changing to `WHERE fieldA IS NOT NULL` would change the number of rows being grouped, possibly changing the original intent.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* include all non-aggregate columns in the `GROUP BY`.  5.7.5 introduced the `SQL_MODE` of `only_full_group_by` to enforce such (while not complaining about some cases where it is actually OK).

When you have a non-aggregate column, the code is free to provide any value it likes for such a column (`xx` in your case).  Given that, then how could the `HAVING` make any rational sense.

This is not a bug; it is a user error.